# A function to output number of weeks using phptime function

Tags: php

28days make up four weeks right? Well, i am trying to write a function which basically returns something like this week1, week2, week3, week4..Week1 is essentially the first 7 days starting from today. But this is as far as i have been able to go.

```
function week() {
    $currentdate = time();
    $numberofdays = 28;
    for ($i=0; $i<$numberofdays; $i++) {
    }
}
```

Comment: if (i%7==0) echo "week: ".$j++;

Comment: @Byron Whitlock, this does not use the current date?

Comment: Please show what output you expect exactly of the date were today.

Comment: Are you trying to return the week current date is in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, are you trying to keep the all the days, such as for a calendar, or simply generate the day which each week starts with?

If you're trying to keep all the days, try this:

```
function week($days = 28) 
{
    //Note, I added the number of days to the function arguments, so that it can be variable without having to change the code
    if(!is_int($days) || $days <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    $start = strtotime("midnight tonight");
    $currentweek = 1;
    $weeks = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++) 
    {
        $weeks[$currentweek][] = $start + ($i * 86400); 

        if(!(i % 7))
        {
            $currentweek++;
        }
    }

    return $weeks;
}
```

This should return an array of timestamps, grouped by weeks, starting from midnight on the day which it is run for `$days` number of days.  If you wanted properly formatted dates, instead of storing the timestamp in the array, store the result of the date() function on the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

see documentation here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

I think you are referring to something like:

```
<?php
$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
                   // 7 days; 24 hours; 60 mins; 60secs
echo 'Now:       '. date('Y-m-d') ."\n";
echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', $nextWeek) ."\n";
// or using strtotime():
echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week')) ."\n";
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

> Now:       2005-03-30 Next Week:
>   2005-04-06 Next Week: 2005-04-06

Comment: If it happens to be around the time of DST switching, this will break. As always when using timestamps for date calculations.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
 * Returns the amount of weeks into the month a date is
 * @param $date a YYYY-MM-DD formatted date
 * @param $rollover The day on which the week rolls over
 */
function getWeeks($date, $rollover)
{
    $cut = substr($date, 0, 8);
    $daylen = 86400;

    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    $first = strtotime($cut . "00");
    $elapsed = ($timestamp - $first) / $daylen;

    $i = 1;
    $weeks = 1;

    for($i; $i<=$elapsed; $i++)
    {
        $dayfind = $cut . (strlen($i) < 2 ? '0' . $i : $i);
        $daytimestamp = strtotime($dayfind);

        $day = strtolower(date("l", $daytimestamp));

        if($day == strtolower($rollover))  $weeks ++;
    }

    return $weeks;
}


$dateNow = date("Y-m-d");
echo getWeeks($dateNow, "monday");
```